# How to change page code in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to change page site_name.com/user/sites (Add button, for example). Where can I find its code? I tried to search in site_name.com/admin/modules but there are too many of them.

EDIT: Sorry, the question is closed. After day of struggle I gave up. Drupal is not for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider creating a template file for that page. Try using `page--admin--modules.tpl.php`.

Check this out: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 2):

/user templates are found in the user module. You can find 4 user templates there.
To know which one to override you can use the [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.
It provides you a checkbox at the bottom of the page and when enabled it shows the candidate preprocess functions and template files for particular regions.
 (As described on the module page, only enable the module is needed because it can mess up the lay-out of some pages.)